# Installing American countertop oven in Europe - Converter Trouble

Tags: electrical, appliances

I'm having some difficulty with a counter-top oven that I purchased in the US and shipped to the Netherlands. The oven itself is 120~V 60Hz and 1500W. I did some research and discovered that here the voltage level is 220V...

When I tried to determine if we needed a converter, the information I found led me to believe that I couldn't just get a normal converter because the wattage level needed for the oven is just too high. I was wondering if anyone knew a way to MacGyver it to work before I have to send it back?

I'm assuming I'll just have to get a European-based counter-top oven instead of going through the whole conversion process but if there's a way of figuring it out without sending a whole big appliance back, it would be great!

Comment: There are plenty of converters that provide that amount of wattage. I personally used a 3000W converter to run US purchased power tools (110V) in Europe (220V). You'd want to buy one with a higher rating than the oven, and also consider difference in frequency (60 Hz in the US vs. 50 Hz in Europe), which might or might not pose a problem.

Comment: @EliIser you know, in the UK they have [transformers *specifically for that*](https://www.its.co.uk/blog/buying-guides/what-is-110v-do-we-need-it/).  UK construction sites are required to use 110VAC (actual, not slang) instead of 240V.  That has nothing to do with America.  It's to improve site safety, as the transformer is center-grounded, so it is 55V from any "hot" to neutral.  Of course the plugs won't fit, but making a construction-110 to NEMA 5 cord is easy.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  First, that was a very foolish thing to do... though I'd make an exception for *certain* built-in ovens whose guts are mainly 240V but have a small amount of 120V conntrols.

The simple fact is: The machinery which turns electricity into heat is very simple, which means **heaters are inexpensive**.

And one more thing: **American heaters are crippled**. You may notice it is 1500 watts, *not a surprise*. Every US heating appliance is 1500W - toaster ovens, hair dryers, curlers, heater-fans, kettles, microwaves, plug-in wall heaters, *you name it*. If it has a NEMA 5-15 plug, it's 1500W *because that is the practical capacity of a 15A 120V circuit*.

In Europe they don't have that problem.  Their sockets support up to 2x what ours do, and so their heat-based appliances are *bigger* when that would make a better appliance.  If you really wanted to ship appliances across oceans, you'd be fitting Europlugs or BS 1363's in your US kitchen.  (which is possible, by the way).

So.  **Simply buy a European version of what you want. Done.**  As for the 120V unit, stick it on Euro Craigslist.  Some expat may be permanently returning to the US and be willing to throw it in their container.  Given how *inherently inexpensive* heating appliances are, I wouldn't ship it in a box.

### OK, so you Really, Really Want that 120V appliance

On UK construction sites, they use 110V for big contractor-grade power tools.  They use a special transformer which gives them 110v "center grounded" so each hot is only 55 volts from earth.  That makes the tools *much safer* than 240V tools.  US *heat-based* appliances will cheerfully run on that, as the transformers are plenty big.  So get one of those transformers and you're all set. And it has resale value.

### One last thing to try

If the heater is *very bespoke specialty*, i.e. actually built by hand in a western country, then the manufacturer may have a phone number they answer.  Ask them if they market this unit internationally.  Ask them if there's a procedure to convert it from 120V to 240V.  Worst thing they'll say is "no", best thing they can say is "Rearrange some jumpers".

Comment: Thank you so much! This is super helpful. I think I will try to call the manufacturer first and see what my options are, but otherwise will start switching to European appliances. Thanks again!